# Simple Blackjack game in Python 2.6.9

Tags: python, beginner, playing-cards, python-2.x

Like the title says, I made a very simple game of Blackjack using Python version 2.6.9. I am relatively new to python and programming so I would really appreciate some constructive criticism to help me improve.

```
from random import shuffle #this imports shuffle which shuffles the     deck

deck = list('234567890JQKA'*4)
for shu in range(0,3):
    shuffle(deck)
value = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8,
         '9':9, '0':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10, 'A':1}      # Creates the shuffled deck

player = [deck.pop() for _ in range(2)]
AI = [deck.pop() for _ in range(2)]     # Deals the cards to the players

stay = False

def player_game():
    global stay
    print "Your hand: %s" % player
    hit = raw_input("Hit or Stay? ")
    if hit == "Hit":
        player.append(deck.pop())
    elif hit == "Stay":
        stay = True
        return stay
    else:
        print "I'm sorry. you need to input 'Hit or Stay'."

while 1:
    player_game()
    total = sum(map(value.get, player, AI))
    if total > 21:
        print "Hand: %s" % player
        print "You busted with a score of: %s" % total
        break
    elif total == 21:
        print player
        print "You win!"
        break
    if stay == True:
        print "You stayed."
        print "Final score: %s" % total
        break
```

Comment: Why do you use such an old Python version? I think we're at a point where no beginner should start with something else than the most recent version (3.6) or if you really want to learn Python 2 then use at least Python 2.7.13.

Answer (score 1):

It is common practice to shorten statements like

```
if stay == True:
```

down to

```
if stay:
```

This'll make your code easier to read (more English-like).

Answer (score 1):

```
from random import shuffle #this imports shuffle which shuffles the     deck
```

The comment isn't really necessary. I wouldn't worry too often about explain imports upfront. I would explain the functions when you use them. In this case, however:

```
shuffle(deck)
```

Is fairly self explanitory.

```
for shu in range(0,3):
```

As you never use `shu`, by convention you would use `_` instead. More importantly, I'm not exactly sure what you hope to get out of shuffling the deck three times. I think once is probably enough.

Using `global` is usually bad practice. You can use the return value of `play_game` to get around this. (I'll leave that as an exercise.)

I would change `while 1:` to `while True:`. Although they do the same thing `True` is considered better style in at least Python.

Comment: Would you mind explaining more of how I can use the return value of 'player_game'? I have tried playing around with it and can't seem to fix the problem without using 'global'.

Answer (score 0):

The program looks pretty good, but the main thing that should be changed is the **global variable** `stay`. Global variables should mostly be avoided, since they make code harder to understand and maintain. I'd only get the input in the `player_game` function and return `True` or `False` if the user wants to stay or hit, and then assign this returned value to the `stay` variable.

---

Then there's a big problem with your `total = sum(map(value.get, player, ai))` line. You're passing the `ai` cards as default values to `value.get`. That means if the player has a invalid card that doesn't exist in the `value` dict, it adds the ai card instead. I think it's not possible to have invalid cards, so you can just change the line to `total = sum(VALUE[card] for card in player)` (that's a generator expression that we pass to `sum`. It's similar to a list comprehension, but is evaluated lazily).

---

Regarding string formatting, in your simple cases you don't need it: `print("Your hand:", player)`, but I also recommend to take a look at the new style string formatting  `"Your hand: {}".format(player)` and if you switch to Python 3.6 the new f-strings `f"Your hand: {player}"`.

I've made some changes to the program and added comments.

```
# This allows you to use Python 3's print function in
# Python 2, so that the program is more compatible.
from __future__ import print_function

from random import shuffle


# Maps the card strings to integer values. This dict should stay
# constant (won't get changed), therefore we use a uppercase name.
# That just tells other programmers that they shouldn't modify this dict.
VALUE = {'2':2, '3':3, '4':4, '5':5, '6':6, '7':7, '8':8,
         '9':9, '0':10, 'J':10, 'Q':10, 'K':10, 'A':1}


def player_input():
    """Return True for stay and False for hit."""
    # A while loop is needed here, if the user inputs something invalid.
    while True:
        # Convert input to lower case to be more user friendly.
        hit = raw_input("(H)it or (s)tay? ").lower()
        # We can also allow `h` or `s` as input.
        if hit in ("hit", "h"):
            return False  # Assign this to the `stay` variable in `main`.
        elif hit in ("stay", "s"):
            return True  # Assign this to the `stay` variable in `main`.
        else:
            print("I'm sorry. you need to input '(h)it or (s)tay'.")


# Put everything into a main function except the global constants.
def main():
    deck = list('234567890JQKA'*4)
    # If the variable isn't needed we usually use `_` as
    # a throwaway variable. `range(3)` is the same as `range(0, 3)`.
    # for _ in range(3):  # Shuffling 3 times is pointless.
    shuffle(deck)
    # Deals the cards to the players.
    player = [deck.pop() for _ in range(2)]
    # Uppercase names are for constants.
    ai = [deck.pop() for _ in range(2)]

    while True:  # `while 1:` is outdated.
        print("Your hand:", player)
        stay = player_input()
        if not stay:
            player.append(deck.pop())

        total = sum(VALUE[card] for card in player)
        if total > 21:
            print("Hand:", player)
            print("You busted with a score of:", total)
            break
        elif total == 21:
            print("Hand:", player)
            print("You win!")
            break
        elif stay:  # == True: isn't needed.
            print("You stayed.")
            print("Final score:", total)
            break


# This makes sure that the program doesn't run
# if it gets imported.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```